# The circle group with $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Assume $z=\operatorname{cis}\theta \in \mathbb{T}$. Why is the order of $z$ infinite if $\theta$ is rational?

Looking for intuition, please.

Comment: Yes, definitely rational.

Comment: What is $\Bbb{T}$?

Comment: @chase $\mathbb{T} = \left \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\right \}$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Note that $\mathbb T \times \mathbb T$ is a torus, and $\mathbb T \times \cdots \times \mathbb T$ $n$ times is referred to as an $n$-dimensional Torus. Does that help explain the terminology? :)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein That certainly explains the notation! I’m more accustomed to calling it “the unit circle in the complex plane.”

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I'm also not familiar with any context in which this is standard, but it made sense to me. Obviously this is also $S^1$.

Answer (score 3):

For it to be of finite order, you need that there exists integers $p,q\ge1$ such that $p\theta=q\pi$. If $\theta$ is rational, this would contradict the fact that $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: Does this group have its own name?

Comment: @Denise I doubt it. As an abstract group $\{\operatorname{cis}(\theta) \mid \theta \in \mathbb Q\}$ under multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ under addition.

Comment: Well, you can call it $\mathbb{Z}$ if you want. They are isomorphic.